# Click pointers on badges [profile feature]

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page

When on my Stack Overflow profile going through my badges I noticed that certain buttons 'that have a function' do not have a pointer, but instead a default cursor.

*As shown in red (button that does have a pointer) as shown in green (button has no pointer but instead a default cursor)*:

[image: As shown in red (button that does have a pointer) as shown in green (button has no pointer but instead a default cursor)]

This does not influence people on pressing these buttons even though these buttons can be useful like the following:

[image]

Would it be useful to add these?

Comment: Those unnatural looking squary freehand circles are a bit distracting.

Comment: @yivi how else would you have shown what buttons its about?

Comment: Why, by drawing the circles by hand, of course. By drawing the circles by hand you put a personal touch that shows care and dedication, and meta readers are more likely to [appreciate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138031/is-there-a-joke-about-freehand-circles-that-im-oblivious-to).

Comment: This has been requested on Meta.SE: [Mouse over cursor for tag badge is different from cursor for regular tag in the profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315848/289905).

Comment: @Xufox you're cross site duplicating [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315848/mouse-over-cursor-for-tag-badge-is-different-from-cursor-for-regular-tag-in-the#comment1035470_315848). :D Oh and it *hasn't* been requested on MSO, it's a bug report - which I suspect is not a bug.